# service --status-all takes too long... what are alternatives?

Tags: server, php, services

The command:

```
service --status-all
```

Takes too long to iterate through all of the services especially when all I want from the output is the name (I don't care if it's running or not).  Is there a faster way to retrieve the name of a service that contains a known character pattern?

With Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 using different service names for php-fpm (php5-fpm in Ubuntu 14.04 and php7.0-fpm in Ubuntu 16.04), developers supporting multiple platforms need to be able to determine the service name.

If I run the below command on a slower computer:

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep -F -- "-fpm" | awk '{print $4}'
```

It takes several seconds (up to 5 seconds) to return "php7.0-fpm".

Developers that have to interact with these services need a faster way to determine the name of the service since they continually change from one OS version to another.

Anyone know of a better and faster way to do this?

In the meantime, I filed this bug here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-service/+bug/1742410

I don't know how else I can accomplish what I need to do quickly...

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that this depends on the version of Ubuntu, why not just check the version instead?

```bsh
case $(lsb_release -sc) in
trusty)
    fpm_service=php5-fpm
    ;;
xenial)
    fpm_service=php7.0-fpm
    ;;
artful)
    fpm_service=php7.1-fpm
    ;;
esac
```

Alternately, you could test for the service files in `/etc/init.d` (since all current FPM packages provide an `/etc/init.d` script):

```bsh
find /etc/init.d/ -type f -iname '*-fpm' -printf "%P\n"
```

Comment: The whole point is that I don't want to have to hard code it against the ubuntu version, but that somewhat helps.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'll go with the following approach:

```
    fpmService=$(ls /etc/init.d 2>&1 | grep -F -- "fpm");
    if [ -z "$fpmService" ]; then
        fpmService=$(ls /lib/systemd/system 2>&1 | grep -F -- "fpm" | grep -o "[^(service)]*" | sed "s/\.$//"
    fi
    if [ -z "$fpmService" ]; then
        fpmService=$(ls /lib/systemd/system 2>&1 | grep -F -- "' . $service . '" | grep -o "[^(service)]*" | sed "s/\.$//")
    fi
```

Stupid, but it works... the service command should still provide us with an interface to do this...

Comment: The second and third `ls | grep` pipes are unnecessarily complex - `find /lib/systemd/system -name '*-fpm*' -exec basename {} .service \;` will get you the result more easily.